# Why is detect-secrets-hook ignoring my audit selections?

Tags: security, devsecops

detect-secrets-hook in my pre-commit is alerting on secrets that are already marked as safe to be committed in the baseline.

I'm running detect-secrets version 1.4.0 on Python 3.11.0 on Windows 11.

To reproduce:

1. Have a file in a git repo containing something that will get caught as a secret. Update something in the file so that it needs to be committed.
2. Create/recreate a secrets baseline with `detect-secrets scan > .secrets.baseline`
3. Resave the baseline file as UTF-8, [because I'm on Windows](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets/issues/272).
4. Run `detect-secrets audit .secrets.baseline` and accept that the secret is okay to be in the file. The segment of the baseline file looks like:

```
"results": {
    "xyz\\dev_local_settings.py": [
      {
        "type": "Secret Keyword",
        "filename": "xyz\\dev_local_settings.py",
        "hashed_secret": "62f4d1d18d106c8e6f3c79df832893f4b6e95c8e",
        "is_verified": false,
        "line_number": 26,
        "is_secret": false
      }
    ]
  },
```

5. Have a pre-commit config that looks like this:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets
    rev: v1.4.0
    hooks:
    -   id: detect-secrets
        args: ['--baseline', '.secrets.baseline']
        exclude: package.lock.json
```

6. Attempt to `git commit -a`.

The pre-commit check will fail on the one known secret:

```
Detect secrets...........................................................Failed
- hook id: detect-secrets
- exit code: 1

ERROR: Potential secrets about to be committed to git repo!


Secret Type: Secret Keyword
Location:    xyz/dev_local_settings.py:26
```

7. Another run of `detect-secrets audit .secrets.baseline` yields "Nothing to audit!"

Am I misunderstanding how detect-secrets works? I would expect it to not alert on a secret that was marked as safe in the baseline.

Comment: did you resolve your issue? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding a comment containing `pragma: allowlist secret` in the offending line.

I didn't try it at first, because the issue was in an `appsettings.json` file of an asp.net project and according to Google json can't have comments. However, seems like Microsoft does allow `//` comments in `appsettings.json`.